# how to find the value in WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-result-id*='true']"))

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Good evening to all. I am new to python and was just doing one of this exercise in Udemy course where we are tasked to prepare a program using webdriver and getting Internet speed test results on speedtest.net. I was stuck when I found some one gave solution of using:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-result-id*='true']"))
```

My question is how and where this value for the CSS SELECTOR can be found on the website. Please explain. Please also give as much insight as you can regarding selenium or web driver and CSS in python.

```
#Libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#Constants
PROMISED_DOWN = 150
PROMISED_UP = 10
TWITTER_EMAIL = "my email"
TWITTER_PASSWORD = "my password"

#Class
class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = Service('D:\Python Related Documents and Programsweb development folder\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.s)
        self.down = None
        self.up = None

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
        time.sleep(5)
        go_botton = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.start-button a')

        go_botton.click()
        #speed_download = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".download-speed")
        speed_download = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span')

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-result-id*='true']"))
        )
        speed_results = self.driver.find_elements(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".result-container-speed span.result-data-large.number.result-data-value"
        )

        self.down, self.up = (float(result.text) for result in speed_results)

        print(f"Down Speed: {self.down}, Up Speed: {self.up}" )

        #go_botton.click()
    def tweet_at_provider(self):
        pass

#Object creation
bot = InternetSpeedTwitterBot()

#Calling methods
bot.get_internet_speed()
bot.get_internet_speed()
```

Comment: What do you mean by - "how and where this value for the CSS SELECTOR can be found on the website", explain it briefly.

Comment: Hi @AbiSaran, Thanks for replying what I am looking for is in the below code how the solver found the value for the CSS SELECTOR on the sppedtest.net site, I mean this element becomes visible only after the defined period and it can be on any website so how to find such a thing is my question.                                                            
 WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-result-id='true']"))

Answer (score 0):

What I do to find the elements?:

1. Open the inspect/dev tool from your browser (I use chrome) using `F12` or `right click --> Inspect` [image]
2. Click on element tab [image]
3. Then make `Ctrl + f` on the element window and new search bar will appear  [image]
4. As you can see that in that bar you can search elements in your page by xpath or CSS.
5. Click in the button [image] located on the top left of your dev tool. Then that element will be located on your dev tool.
6. If in your search bar you write a xpath or css selector the element will be highlighted in your screen, in that way you will know what is the selector you can use [image]

**Some doc:**

- How to find elements by CSS selector?: [Small guide for CSS](https://devqa.io/selenium-css-selectors/)
- How to find elements by XPATH selector?: [Small guide for xpath](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/find-element-by-xpath-in-selenium)

Comment: @Jacky Ruby Thanks for replying but what I am looking for is in the below code how the solver found the value for the CSS SELECTOR on the sppedtest.net site, I mean this element becomes visible only after the defined period and it can be on any website so how to find such a thing is my question. WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-result-id='true']"))

Comment: You have to understand the page you are trying to automate. Inpect the element you want to use and try to get a locator (In your case a CSS selector) once you know what is the element you have to understand what is the condition for using that element. In your case the key is: `visibility_of_element_located` because the element can be in the page but is hidden, so when you use `visibility_of_element_located` you are not only waiting for the element to be attached on the dom, you are waiting to BE VISIBLE. So everything depend on how your page works. Once you know it you you can act accordingly

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you are making to  explain. But without an example I am clue less. Please if you could show me in this particular case how to go about it step by step probably with a screen shot, It would a great help.